# Openshift MysQL Tomcat Connection is null

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, database-connection, openshift

i am new in Openshift, trying to host my application, but can not connect to MySQL database in Openshift.

This is my code to connect to MySQL:

```
public class DBUtill {

public Connection getConnection() {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.2.191.130:3306/database";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

But it doesnt work, because im always getting con = null

But when i put same code directly in jsp page, everything works fine:

```
<%@page import="com.java.testapp.db.DBUtill"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<% 

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.2.191.130:3306/database";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

DBUtill utill = new DBUtill();

out.println( "Connection: " +utill.getConnection()); // CONNECTION = null

out.println( "Connection: " +con); // IT WORKS!


%>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not understand why im getting con=null when using DBUtill class to connect to MySQL. But connection works perfectly directly in jsp.
Please, help